# Android: Adding SEND_SMS permission causes gradle build to fail

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm starting a simple app to send an SMS at the press of a button. I'm testing this on my mobile phone since i need the network. The app build fine the first time but the button press didn't do anything since i forgot to add the permission `android.permission.SEND_SMS`. Once i added that then faced with following error.

```
Error:java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\myApp\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_ (Access is denied)
 C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\myApp\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_ (Access is denied)
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.android.myapp">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

If I delete the `uses-permission` tag the app builds without a problem. But when I add it it fails. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

**Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.android.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
}
```

Comment: Port your gradle and also logcat of gradle.

Comment: clean your android project

Comment: I've tried cleaning it, but it didn't help

Comment: What error is gradle logcat showing while sync? your build.gradle looks perfect.

Comment: may be due to SEND_SMS comes in dangerous permission category.. as you are using 23 target  I dont know about studio but  in eclipse it will crash on run time.. it might be possible studio chekcking at compile time,try a normal permission then build your gradle.

Comment: There is no logcat output. The FileNotFoundError is what I get in the "messages". @Ancee I tried a normal permission and the build was successful. So I think you're on to something. In that case what do I do to build with a dangerous permission?

Comment: i have used a run time code in my launch activity... check this .. http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html and there are many demo available too.. try this

Comment: @Ancee That partially helps, but even with the realtime permissions I have to have the `uses-permission` tag. Whenever I do I get this error

Comment: @xv47.. try target with 22.. if it run fine then do some effort on permission things.. else some thing other is going wrong..

Comment: @Ancee I tried that as well, but no dice. I even wiped out the project and rewrote it (its a very basic project), wiped out and reinstalled android studio + sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! To anyone else trying to figure this out, you need both `android.permission.SEND_SMS` and `android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS` in your manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.android.myapp">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

It means you don't have permission to edit or modify, 
Please "intermediates" folder and clean again and build. 
Hopefully it will work.
 C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\myApp\app\build\intermediates\

or check permissions something etc.

If you're just importing some jar files, you could try to remove them and add them one at a time. This will help you determine which one of them causes the error.